# Interdependence between leverages and residuals

Tags: regression, residuals, diagnostic, cooks-distance

According to the following online quote I read online:

> It’s worth noting that an observation can have a high absolute value
> for a standardized residual, yet have a low value for leverage.

My thoughts are the following: the leverage has a direct impact on the fitted values of the model. That is, a high leverage is needed when our observed value is far away from the fitted model. That is, the residual is big. So how can there be a big low leverage and a big residual? What am I missing here?

Comment: The key is to compare this to the closely related concept of influence: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=leverage+influence+regression

Answer (score 5):

Leverage can be heuristically defined as "how unusual the case is in terms of its values on the IVs." This doesn't say anything about how much it distorts the relationship between IVs and DVs, only how *rare* it is as a *predictor*. For a bivariate case, leverage can be formally defined as:

$$
\large
\text{leverage} = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{\sum (x-\bar{x})^2} 
$$

where $n$ is the number of observations, $x_i$ is a given raw data point, $\bar{x}$ is the mean of $x$, and the denominator $\sum x^2$ is the sum of the squared $x$ values. Keep in mind that if $x_i$ is close to the value of $\bar{x}$, this will essentially reduce to zero and thus the equation will reduce to $\frac{1}{n}$ and have very little impact, so this formula is sensitive to distances from the mean (how far away our given $x$ is from where it "should be').

A residual on the other hand is essentially "how bad a regression is at guessing a given data point." It is formally defined as:

$$
\large
\text{residual} = y - \hat{y}, 
$$

where $y$ is the given raw data value of $y$ and $\hat{y}$ is the *predicted* value of $y$. Notice now that the first formula is explicitly related to $x$ while the second formula is defined by the relationship between $x$ and $y$, as $\hat{y}$ is the predicted value of $y$ given $x$. So while leverage *can* have an impact on the residuals and the overall relationship on the coefficients, the leverage is more loosely related to the absolute distance of residuals than one may think.

Here is a simulated example of data using R programming which has one extreme value of $x$ which has a high leverage but otherwise does not have a large residual, nor does it severely distort the relationship between $x$ an $y$:

```
#### Leverage Function ####
lev <- function(x){
  n <- length(x)
  lhs <- 1/n
  rhs <- ((x-mean(x))^2) / sum((x - mean(x))^2)
  lev <- lhs + rhs
  return(lev)
}

#### Simulate Data ####
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- (2*x) +  rnorm(10)

#### Add Outlier ####
x.new <- c(x,8)
y.new <- c(y,16) # because y = 2x + e

#### Check Leverage ####
lev(x.new)

#### Merge into Tibble ####
df <- data.frame(x.new,y.new) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(leverage = lev(x.new))
df

#### Plot ####
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x.new,
             y.new))+
  geom_point(aes(size=leverage))+
  geom_smooth(
    method = "lm",
    color = "darkred",
    se = F,
    formula = y ~ x
  )+
  geom_vline(
    xintercept = mean(x.new),
    linetype = "dashed"
  )+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  labs(x="X",
       y="Y",
       title = "Leverage of Points",
       size="Amount of Leverage")
```

You can see the relationship in the plot below, where the size of the data points indicates it's respective leverage. The dashed line shows the mean of $x$, and you can see points which stray far away from that tend to increase in leverage but are otherwise closely fit around the regression line.

[image]

Now of course leverage and residuals have a close relationship when it comes to things like *influence*, which is the amount a data point changes the coefficients. To indicate the difference, we can add a very influential point here which also has high leverage, then fit the original data and the data with the influential point to compare:

```
#### Fit Model to Original Data ####
fit1 <- lm(y.new ~ x.new,
           df)

##### Create New Bizarro Point and Refit ####
b.data <- df %>% 
  add_row(x.new = 6,
          y.new = 30,
          leverage = lev(6))

fit2 <- lm(y.new ~ x.new,
           b.data)

#### Check Coefficients ####
coef(fit1)
coef(fit2)
```

We can see now that `fit2` has a relatively inflated slope compared to `fit1`:

```
> coef(fit1)
(Intercept)       x.new 
  0.1452786   2.0558130 
> coef(fit2)
(Intercept)       x.new 
  0.4654817   2.9833302
```

We can showcase how refitting the data can showcase not only how this new data point creates a large residual, but also reweights the residual of the previous point that had not substantial influence but still high leverage.

```
#### Augment Data ####
library(broom)
aug1 <- augment(fit1)
aug2 <- augment(fit2)

#### Save Plots ####
p1 <- aug1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x.new,
             y=y.new))+
  geom_point(size=3)+
  geom_smooth(
    method = "lm",
    color = "darkred",
    se=F
  )+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x.new, 
                   yend = .fitted))+
  labs(x="X",
       y="Y",
       title="Original Fit")

p2 <- aug2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x.new,
             y=y.new))+
  geom_point(size=3)+
  geom_smooth(
    method = "lm",
    color = "darkred",
    se=F
  )+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x.new, 
                   yend = .fitted))+
  labs(x="X",
       y="Y",
       title="Refitted Data")

#### Plot Them Together ####
ggpubr::ggarrange(p1,p2)
```

Comparing the two, we can now see the difference (note here that the size of the data points are now all the same to simplify). We can also see that in the initial fit, the distance between the data point and the regression line is barely noticeable (shown with the black line coming from the data point), whereas in the second fit, we can see that the new data point reweights the relationship between $x$ and $y$ and consequently makes both itself and the previously large leverage point now influential, as depicted with the longer residual lines:

[image]

Comment: I believe the expression of leverage in simple linear regression takes the form $$\frac1n+\frac{(x_i-\bar x)^2}{\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected it and added a new plot of the leverage points, which didn't really change much but are nonetheless more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

*Leverage* is a measure of how far the value of the independent variable is from that variable for other observations.

The *residuals* (standardized, studentized, or whatever) are measures of how far the observation is from the regression line.

And, though you didn't mention it, there are also *influential points*, which are observations that have a big effect on the coefficients.

Suppose you are modeling weight as a function of height in adult human males, and you have a sample of (say) 200. Then if, by chance, someone who is 2 meters tall is in your data set, he will be an outlier on height and have high leverage. But, if his weight is near what the rest of the data implies (say 130 kg) then he will have a low residual.  But if his weight is much lower, he will have a big residual.

It would be like the difference between an American football lineman (very tall, very heavy) and a center in basketball (very tall, sometimes not so heavy).

(For an extreme case, Manute Bol was 2.3 meters tall and weighed only 91 kg).